# Calculated field from another table in OpenSQL

Tags: abap, opensql

The below example works in MySql, how can I achive this in OpenSql?

```
 SELECT StudentID, Name,
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StudentExam
      WHERE StudentExam.StudentID = Student.StudentID )
      AS ExamsTaken
   FROM Student
   ORDER BY ExamsTaken DESC;
```

SAP_BASIS version: 740-13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use `INNER JOIN` and `GROUP BY`? If you want to present also the students who have taken no exams then you can achieve it with `UNION`.

```
SELECT StudentID, Name, COUNT(*) AS ExamsTaken
  FROM Student INNER JOIN StudentExam
  ON Student.StudentID = StudentExam.StudentID
  GROUP BY StudentID, Name
UNION
SELECT StudentID, Name, 0 AS ExamsTaken
  FROM Student
  WHERE StudentID NOT IN (SELECT StudentID FROM StudentExam WHERE StudentID =
    Student.StudentID)
  ORDER BY ExamsTaken DESC.
```

And here's some real life example in OpenSQL.

```
REPORT zzz.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  SELECT scarr~carrid, scarr~carrname, COUNT(*) AS examstaken
    FROM scarr INNER JOIN sflight
    ON scarr~carrid = sflight~carrid
    GROUP BY scarr~carrid, scarr~carrname
  UNION
  SELECT scarr~carrid, scarr~carrname, 0 AS examstaken
    FROM scarr
    WHERE carrid NOT IN ( SELECT carrid FROM sflight WHERE carrid = scarr~carrid )
  ORDER BY examstaken DESCENDING " <== applies to the union of both SELECT
  INTO TABLE @DATA(g_tab_result).
BREAK-POINT.
```

Here is the result.

[image: OpenSQL query result]

Comment: INNER JOIN is not good, because that will not list the the students without exams. LEFT JOIN lists them, but with `examstakes = 1` instead of 0

Comment: Then go with `UNION` for missing entries. I have updated my answer.